# MySQL: Select all data between range of two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I make a query that select everything between two dates.

```
SELECT * FROM applications WHERE `datum` >='2013-11%' AND `datum`<='2014-04%';
```

I was trying to do something like that but that doesn't work that only returns one record.
Can someone show me how to make it show everything between a range of two dates.

Datum's type is Datetime. 
like 2013-11-02 12:21:00

Comment: what is the datatype of `datum` ?

Comment: Also, are you sure there are multiple entries in the database that should fall under those conditions?

Comment: Datetime format e.g. 2013-11-02 12:21:00

Comment: Step #1 is to ensure use of a proper date-time field, step #2 is to not try to apply `'%'` which is for LIKE ..

Comment: @Helpful I'm very sure.

Comment: Could you please execute the SQL in phpMyAdmin to verify it is returning more than 1 row, and please provide the PHP code.

Comment: there are 2k entries in database. Range between 2013-11 and 2014-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [between](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) statement, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM applications WHERE datum BETWEEN '2013-11-01' AND '2014-04-01';
```

You are using a wildcard in your queries, so just figure out what dates you want to use and you are good to rock and roll.

Comment: Actually the OP seems to want the whole month of april, not just the first day. Also, assuming it's a datetime or timestamp column, you're actually just getting '2014-04-01 00:00:00', not the whole day.

Comment: This is giving me just one record. Idk whats wrong.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM applications WHERE datum BETWEEN '2013-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-01 00:00:00';`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you do indeed have more than one row?

Comment: Neil, thanks it's working now I was entering wrong enddate. :p

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is used in `like` searches, which applies to (var)char and text columns.

```
SELECT * FROM applications WHERE `datum` >='2013-11-01' AND `datum`<='2014-04-31 23:59:59';
```

In MySQL it's safe to use 31 as the upper end of a month, even for february.

Comment: Why not just `< '2015-05-01'`? In any case, I believe it's important to also account for times, as shown (so +1).

Comment: Well, if the user specifies a given date, not necessarily the end of the month, do you have some logic in your code that transforms the date given by the user, so you can more conveniently write your sql query? I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.. WHERE datum >= '2012-01-01' AND datum <= '2012-12-31'
```

***http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b43b/2***

Comment: check my answer with sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$query="SELECT * FROM applications WHERE `datum` between '2013-11-01' AND '2014-04-01'";
```

or

```
$query="SELECT * FROM applications WHERE `datum` WHERE  `datum` >=  '2013-11-01' and  `datum` <=  '2014-04-01' ";
```

both are working

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot, it's working now I was using the wrong enddate.