# select data from range of two column mysql

Tags: mysql

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129217/mysql-select-all-data-between-range-of-two-dates) shows everything between two dates, I want to make something that selects data that only has "2013-11-28".

```
id   Check_in               Check_out
1    2013-11-01             2013-12-01
2    2014-01-01             2014-01-07
3    2013 11-20             2014-01-03
```

So when I select "2013-11-28", it will only select id '1' and '3'.

Comment: Um, isn't that exactly what `between` does in the post you referenced?  It would provide your expected results.  Or you could use `>=` with `<=`. A little unclear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get records with `Check_in`'s year is `2013` and month is `11`, you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE year(Check_in) = '2013' AND month(Check_in) = '11';
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4c3f9/1)

If you want to get records that `Check_in` is before `2013-11-28` and `Check_out` is after `2013-11-28`, then you can try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE Check_in <= '2013-11-28' AND Check_out >= '2013-11-28';
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4c3f9/2)